# Discord bot replies to its messages (python)

Tags: python, discord, bots

```
if message.content.startswith('Привет'):
    print('[command]: Задан вопрос3 ')
    await message.channel.send('Привет ' + random.choice(list2) + '!')
if(messageAuthor == "Бот-Бобот#0869"):
    return
```

I want the discord bot to respond to the message "Hello", but the response also contains the word "Hello"
How to prevent a bot from responding to itself?

Comment: You can validate `message.author`

Comment: Did not help(((

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just check if the author of the message is the bot itself. You can do so like this:

```
if not message.author.bot:
   do_stuff()
else:
   pass # author is bot, just ignore
```

Try if this works for you

```
if message.author.bot:
    return
    
# we will reach this point if and only if the author is NOT a bot
if message.content.startswith('Привет'):
    print('[command]: Задан вопрос3 ')
    await message.channel.send('Привет ' + random.choice(list2) + '!')
```

Comment: Even more, you can delete `else` block at all :D

Comment: Does not work. Where exactly should I put your code? Sorry, I'm just a beginner and I could be wrong :')

Comment: @369, you probably need to learn language basics before starting to code bots.

Comment: `if not message.author.bot and message.content.startswith('Привет'):`